# Django how to display subquerys in Template

Tags: django, django-templates

My view:

```
credits = Credit.objects.filter(account=OuterRef('pk')).values('account_id').annotate(sum_credits=Sum('amount'))
debits = Debit.objects.filter(account=OuterRef('pk')).values('account_id').annotate(sum_debits=Sum('amount'))
dif = Account.objects.annotate(credit_sum=Subquery(credits.values('sum_credits')),debit_sum=Subquery(debits.values('sum_debits')),balance=F('credit_sum') F('debit_sum')).values_list('name', 'balance')
```

My template:

```
{% for account in dif %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ account }}</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

result :

```
('andrea', 10)          
('mosca', 20)
```

How to remove the parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned values are [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). You can access them using indices, for example:

```
{{ account.0 }}'s balance is {{ account.1 }}
```

will print

```
andrea's balance is 10
```

Comment: work fine thnx, when i do the same with credits , {% for credit in credits  %} give this error This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery, can foorlop credit?

Comment: Yes, you can't use a subquery directly. What is your expected output? I suggest you to post  this as a separate question though.

Comment: thanky for you help, to show how much credits have the user in the same table html, i try with zip list but does work

Comment: Ah, not tried this but I believe it is as simple as adding `debit_sum` and `credit_sum` to your `values_list` like you did with `balance`.